# Android menu button, to refresh page

Tags: android

What code would i add so that when the menu button refresh is pressed it will refresh the webview that is in my application.?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView WV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WV.loadUrl("http://home.btconnect.com/MrJFisher/");



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.item1){
        WebView.reload();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
};
```

beginner at this. so i do apologise.

Comment: post the rest of your activity code that contains the WebView.

Comment: changed it should be all there

Comment: see my edit, you need to change `WebView.reload()` to `WV.reload()` Also I would strongly suggest you take some time to practice your java fundamentals and syntax a bit before you dive to deep into an Android project. It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;        

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://home.btconnect.com/MrJFisher/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }  

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.item1){
            mWebView.reload();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method reload() from the type WebView"

Comment: you need a WebView instance first. reload() is not static.

Comment: just the call to reload() in your webView instance. Somewhere in your code, you have initialized it, right? Just keep the variable and call reaload when necessary.

Comment: i have edited my message have i put .reload() in the correct place

Comment: Your WebView variable WV should be a class variable. Then you can access it in the onOptionsItemSelected method.

Comment: how do i make it a class variable ?

Comment: @M0n5terBunny declare it above onCreate() and initialize it inside of onCreate(). And I suggest even more brushing up on your Java fundamentals and syntax!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()== R.id.item1){
        WV.reload(); 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

See the [WebView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the reload method. This is the correct one. Anyway, it should return true after it.