# Refresh webView with multiple tabs

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm making an Android app that uses an appBarLayout with tabs in it and webViews that load an external URL underneath it. In the toolbar menu I want to add a refresh option that refreshes only the current tab. I couldn't figure out how to get it working in my specific case. I already  tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563970/7683741) but when I press the refresh button, the app crashes.

**EDIT:** I think the only part I need to edit is `if (id == R.id.action_refresh)` in my MainActivity.java. But because I have 4 tabs (Tab0, Tab1 etc.) I think it shouldn't say `Tab0.webview.reload();`, but just the current tab which is open.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //TODO
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        //What comes here?
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab0 tab0 = new Tab0();
                return tab0;
            case 1:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 3:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Tab 0";
            case 1:
                return "Tab 1";
            case 2:
                return "Tab 2";
            case 3:
                return "Tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.my.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Tab0.java

```java
public class Tab0 extends Fragment {

WebView webview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab0, container, false);
    webview = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview0);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    return rootView;
}
}
```

My tab0.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.my.app.MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter">

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone help me with implementing the refresh button? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qNFR0fvy) After following Ocean15's solution

Answer (score 0):

The `WebView.reload()` should be the way to go for you as mentioned in the post you refered.

If your app crash because of it then you probably do soemthing wrong. What is the crash error?

Use following in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
    ((WebView) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.webview0)).reload();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the only part I need to edit is `if (id == R.id.action_refresh)` in my MainActivity.java. But when I write this: `Tab0.webview.reload();` it says: "Non-static field 'webview' cannot be referenced  from a static context"
Maybe because webview isn't declared in MainActivity.java?
And because I have 4 tabs it shouldn't say Tab0.webview.reload(), but just the current tab which is open.

Comment: @Hamata6 Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it can't resolve the reload method?

Comment: @Hamata6 Ah thats a Fragment, my bad. Updated again :)

Comment: It compiles, but when i hit the refresh button, it crashes with the following logcat: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qNFR0fvy)
(Sorry, I think my app is really complicated for just showing 4 webpages XD)

Comment: @Hamata6  Your memory might not be enough. Try to rais it and post your results